# How can I check if an external link contains playable media before opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I would like to check if an external link contains playable media before opening the link in a new tab. I am attempting to do this in an `if else` format so that I can modify the link if it does not contain playable media.

I am struggling to figure out how to check for this if both links end in `.mp4` in the URL. Essentially one link gets an XML error and the other does not, and I am trying to account for these differences and dynamically adjust the link before opening it.  I've also just tried to check for strings on the new page to see if there is an XML error, but the script stops as soon as a new tab is opened with `window.open`, and `chrome.tabs.create` doesn't seem to work.

I'm new to Javascript. Any advice would be helpful.

```js
//var win = window.open(modifiedLink, '_blank').focus();
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: modifiedLink,
    selected: true,
  })

var checkForErrors = document.querySelector("body > div.header > span").innerHTML;

if (checkForErrors.includes("This XML file does not appear to have any style")) {
    modifiedLink = modifiedLink.replace('/ask_video/', '/encoded/')
    window.open(modifiedLink, '_blank').focus();
}
```

Comment: No one can help you unless you post your manifest.json and html and js.

Comment: @L.Mucker Where do you plan to use this extension? (URL of the website)